# Use [STAThread] in a console program in C#

Tags: c#, console, sta

I have written code for a C# console application. It copies a clipboard value to a file, and it runs without any error.

Now I want to use it in another C# project with other code.

I use  `[STAThread]` after `class{}`, but it give me an error:

> :: Attribute 'STAThread' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'method' declarations.

What can I do?

Comment: Attributes are placed *before* the item they modify, not *after*. So, if previously you've placed `[STAThread]` *after* `class`, that has just (by coincidence) worked by appearing in the right place in the file such that the first declared *member* of the class was the thing that should have been modified.

Comment: It is much stricter than that, [STAThread] will only ever have an affect when it is placed on the Main() entrypoint of a program.  Creating another thread and using Thread.SetApartmentState() before you start it is technically possible.

Answer (score 13):

You can only put `[STAThread]` above the entry point method (not class) and only once in a library. What is your project type that you're trying to copy this code to? Does it even require the STA attribute? Is the method static?

The error is saying you're putting `[STAThread]` on something other than an method.

Post up your code.